# Client side button must spawn a third party website login page such as google.com

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

This is a large MVC project. We need to add a button to one of the views that will start another, totally independent website. If I were to do that in a browser it would for instance be "http://google.com". It is purely intended to assist the users in finding this website which may be moved between multiple hosted servers. The current web should continue as if nothing had happened.

```
        <%if (ViewBag.Enroller != null) { %>
            <td style="padding: 3px 0px 3px 6px;">
                <%
                    Html.DevExpress().Button(settings =>
                    {
                        settings.Name = "FingerEnrollerButton";
                        settings.Text = "Enrol Fingers";
                        //settings.RouteValues = new { Action = "EnrolFingers", Controller = "Employee" };
                        settings.UseSubmitBehavior = false;
                        settings.ClientSideEvents.Click = "function(s, e) { ??? THIS MUST BE THE URL IN ViewBag.Enroller  ??? }"; 
                    })
                    .Render();
                %>
            </td>
       <% } %>
```

It is purely intended to assist the users in finding this website which may be moved between multiple hosted servers. The current web should continue as if nothing had happened.

Comment: should the site open in a new tab/window/etc?

Comment: "We need to add a button to one of the views that will start another, totally independent website"  You've just described an HTML Anchor tag.

Comment: `<a href="http://www.example.com">Click here to visit Example website</a>` ...or have we missed the point? (P.S. add `_target="blank"` if you need it to open in a new tab). I see no need for any server-side code here (except to inject the value from the viewbag, which is trivial e.g. `<a href="@ViewBag.SiteURL">@ViewBag.SiteName</a>` or similar). I can't see a need for any JavaScript either. P.P.S. If you want to make it look like a button instead of a link, then just use some CSS.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for the quick response. My problem is with the exact syntax. Note the DevExpress button in my code : .ClientSideEvents.Click = ??

Comment: Yes but our point is that you don't need anything as complicated as that button to do this job. Keep it simple, use a hyperlink - that's what they're designed for.

Comment: Sorry all, but that is the whole point. I must adhere to the style, theme, CSS et al of the rest of the application.